# Spotify ::: playing songs using osascript and Python

Tags: python, spotify, osascript, echonest

I am running a `python` script in order to play two `Spotify` songs in a row via `Echonest api`.
Apparently, there's  something wrong with this `osacript`  syntax:

```
def play(id1, id2):
    print 'playing', id1, 'then', id2
    os.system("osascript -e 'tell application \"Spotify\" to play tracks \"%s\" and \"%s\"'" % (id1,id2,))
```

when I print the output to a file:

```
   sys.stdout.write("playlist\n\n")
```

I get the proper `foreign_id` for both tracks:

```
 `playing spotify:track:172TCtYnKdqRFPGjeGFzgc then spotify:track:5e2PJY0XHGcCLWxZj7UFpR`
```

what is wrong then?

**NOTE**: playing only one song works fine.